# Sharing in google+ IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-plus

I want to share posts in Google+ from my app, i've done all in this tutorial:
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share#adding_basic_sharing

more then 1 time ...

The problem is:

```
@IBAction func postToGoogle(sender: UIButton) {

    var shareDialog : GPPShareBuilder = GPPShare().shareDialog()

    shareDialog.setPrefillText("Check This out")

    shareDialog.setURLToShare(NSURL(string: "https://developers.ggoe.com/+/"))

    shareDialog.setCallToActionButtonWithLabel("BookMark", URL: NSURL(string: "https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/"),deepLinkID: "")

    shareDialog.open()

}
```

When pressed postToGoogle always gets this in the console:

> 'You must specify |clientID| for |GPPSignIn|'

But in my viewDidLoad:

```
 signIn = GPPSignIn.sharedInstance()
    signIn?.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = true
    signIn?.shouldFetchGoogleUserID = true
    signIn?.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = true

    signIn?.clientID = "89239876213876321yuwqiuhwq.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    signIn?.scopes = [kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin]
    signIn?.delegate = self
```

As you can see i already assign client ID. Even when i do sign in, all works fine.

ps:this client id is fake.

Help me fix this error please. 
Thanks in advance
ADS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the problem:

added in vewDidLoad:

```
gppShare = GPPShare.sharedInstance()
```

changed de button action to:

```
 var shareDialog = gppShare?.shareDialog()

    shareDialog?.setPrefillText("Check This out")

    shareDialog?.setURLToShare(NSURL(string: "https://developers.google.com/+/"))

    shareDialog?.setCallToActionButtonWithLabel("BookMark", URL: NSURL(string: "https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/"),deepLinkID: "")

    shareDialog?.open()
```

It's now calling the shared dialog. But its still missing deep link.

Comment: Did you enable deep links in the developer console?

Answer (score 1):

This is worked for me without using Google Plus SDK :

```
@IBAction func googlePlusShare(sender: AnyObject) {

    let urlstring = "https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share/basic-share"

    let shareURL = NSURL(string: urlstring)

    let urlComponents = NSURLComponents(string: "https://plus.google.com/share")

    urlComponents!.queryItems = [NSURLQueryItem(name: "url", value: shareURL!.absoluteString)]

    let url = urlComponents!.URL!

    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        let svc = SFSafariViewController(URL: url)
        svc.delegate = self
        self.presentViewController(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        debugPrint("Not available")
    }
}
```

---

```
// MARK: - SFSafariViewControllerDelegate

@available(iOS 9.0, *)

func safariViewControllerDidFinish(controller: SFSafariViewController)
{

    controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

---

First import :
import SafariServices

N.B: This features available from iOS 9.0 and Without Google SDK.

Comment: I have tried with above code, but didn't work for me.
I am run code in iOS 11.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me:

```
@IBAction func shareClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
  var shareDialog = GPPShare.sharedInstance().nativeShareDialog();

  // This line will fill out the title, description, and thumbnail from
  // the URL that you are sharing and includes a link to that URL.
  shareDialog.setURLToShare(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: kShareURL));

  shareDialog.open();
}
```

[Full project sources on GitHub](https://github.com/gguuss/gplus-ios-swift/tree/master/share).